# sed remove and replace certain match

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have the following in a file.

```
A 01/13/13 \\0101 \\0102 \\0103
C 04/19/13 \\0301 \\0302 \\0303 \\0304 \\0305
F 04/05/13 \\0602 \\0603 \\0604
```

And i want to replace the first `\\` with the letter at the beginning of the line, and an underscore. Its always one letter. And remove everything afterwards. There is only one space between each section of the lines if that helps.

The desired outcome should be

```
A 01/13/13 A_0101
C 04/19/13 C_0301
F 04/05/13 F_0602
```

I tried using grep, how can i do this using sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is probably better suited to handling this

```
awk '{sub(/../, $1"_", $3); print($1, $2, $3)}' file.txt
A 01/13/13 A_0101
C 04/19/13 C_0301
F 04/05/13 F_0602
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to enable extended regular expressions by passing the `-r` flag.

```
sed -re 's/^(.) (\S+) \\\\(\S+).*$/\1 \2 \1_\3/' file
```

Output

```
A 01/13/13 A_0101
C 04/19/13 C_0301
F 04/05/13 F_0602
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `awk` like this

```
awk '{sub(/\\\\/,x);print $1,$2,$1"_"$3}' file
A 01/13/13 A_0101
C 04/19/13 C_0301
F 04/05/13 F_0602
```